# Programatically create customer cart in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, customer, addtocart

I have tried the below code but the cart is not creating:

```
public function addcustomercart()
{
    $itemId = 59;
    $price = 160;
    $qty = 1;
    $email = "test@test.in";
    $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
    $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    $customer->loadByEmail($email);
    $quote = $this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote

    $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
    // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly 
    //   echo json_encode($quote->getquoteId());
    // exit;
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
    $quote->setCurrency();
    $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

    //add items in quote

    $product = $this->product->load($itemId);
    $product->setPrice($price);
    $quote->addProduct(
        $product, intval($qty));

    return $quote->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few blog already exit.

In my suggestion you can use

https://webkul.com/blog/create-quote-and-order-programmatically-in-magento2/

**There are some change need in this code for your requirement**

**Just remove**

```
 if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
            //If not avilable then create this customer 
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($orderData['email']) 
                    ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
            $customer->save();
        }
```

Comment: Tried the way you have mentioned above but the cart is not creating:

Comment: :i tried the way you have mentioned but it is not working